# SharePoint Online throws error when trying to get thumbnail for video file using '/_layouts/15/getpreview.ashx?path='

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-api

I am using SharePoint endpoint to get document preview for document. I am able to retrieve preview for document. but, facing issue with video files as it throws below error:

This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/getpreview.ashx?path=https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/testlibrary/sagarvideo.mp4 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Though mp4 file is supported by SharePoint which we can verify by using below endpoints:

https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/getpreview.ashx?action=supportedtypes

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.